# Удаление пустых строк из массива

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Имеется строковый массив mas, данные которого необходимо сохранить в *txt-файл*.

Я удаляю пустые строки таким методом: `mas.Where(n => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(n));`, но в конечном итоге сохраняются и полные и пустые строки.

Что требуется для полного удаления?

Comment: ну это смотря как вы удаляете. Скорее всего не происвоив результат метода Where никакой переменной

Comment: А как можно присвоить значение?

Comment: вы не умеете присваивать значения переменным? Тогда вам имеет смысл почитать самые-самые основы языка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var array = new[] { "abc", "cde", "", " " };
var result = array.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\result.txt", result);
```